# How do I run the leaderboard example on my ubuntu VPS?

Tags: meteor

If I run the following commands on my ubuntu VPS:

curl install.meteor.com | sh

meteor create --example leaderboard

cd leaderboard
   meteor

And after setting up my virtual host on apache2 for domain.com. Do I need to do anything further for this example to work, or do I just go to domain.com:3000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you aren't being blocked by a firewall.  For ufw, it should be 'sudo ufw allow 3000';

You *don't* need Apache for that though, just browse to domain.com:3000.

Is it not working?